# Is the series convergent? Give a propf or counter-example

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ be a convergent series with $b_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$, and suppose p > 1. Is $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n)^p$$  convergent? Justify your answer with a proof or give a counterexample.

My guess is the if the series is convergent, let's assume its sum is X, then the sum of the other series should be $X^p$. I am not sure if that assumption is correct. The question demands a proof so I can't just guess.

Comment: No, the assumption is not correct.  It is not even true for finite sums.  Note that $x^2 + y^2 \neq (x+y)^2 = x^2 + \color{red}{2xy}+y^2$.

Comment: Your conjecture is not true. For instance, for $b_n = 1/2^n$, you have $\sum b_n = 1$, while $\sum b_n^2 = \frac13$.

Comment: As for a hint on how to proceed... note that since the sum is convergent, there must be a point at which from that point on all terms are less than $1$ and that $x^p<x$ when $0<x<1$ and $p>1$

Answer (score 1):

If the series is convergent, then the sequence $\{b_n\}$ coverges to $0.$

For $n>N, |b_n| < 1$

And $|b_n^p| < |b_n|$

The series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

By limit comparison test since $b_n \to 0$

$$\frac{(b_n)^p}{b_n}=(b_n)^{p-1}\to 0$$

therefore  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n)^p$ converges or as an alternative since eventually $0\le b_n<1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n)^p\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{n=0}^∞b_n$ is convergent, $\lim_{x\to ∞}b_n=0$

Therefore, past a cerain value of $n$, $b_n<1$

When $b_n<1$, and $p>1$, $(b_n)^p<b_n$

So, by the comparison test comparison test, $\sum_{n=0}^∞(b_n)^p$ is convergent